# Tough probability distribution question with integral over sample space not 1

Tags: probability, integration, derivatives

$\frac{df}{dlogw} = c w^{-0.5} $ where f is the fraction of patients with a particular disease and w is the ratio of weight of patient's liver/patient's weight. If the probability that a patient of any weight has a disease is 60%, what is c? I've tried to integrate the probability density function over the entire sample space (weight of patient's liver/weight of patient = 0 to some realistic value) and set that value to 6/10 instead of the usual 1. However, this gives me crazy values.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Say $W:=W_L/W_P,$ where $W_L$ is the RV describing the weight of a persons liver and $W_P$ is the RV describing a person's weight.

We will need a joint distribution for $(W_L,W_P)$ to be able to answer this.

Let $g(w) = \log w$ so that by the chain rule, $$\frac{df}{dg}=\frac{df}{dw}\frac{dw}{dg} = \frac{\frac{df}{dw}}{\frac{dg}{dw}}=cw^{-0.5}.$$

$\frac{dg}{dw}=\frac{1}{w}$ so $\frac{df}{dw}=cw^{-1.5},$ so $f(w)=c_1-2/3 \cdot c\ w^{-3/2}.$ Since $f$ represents a probability, $f\in(0,1).$

We know that: $$E_{W_L}[f(W_L/W_P)|W_P=w_p]=\int_0^1 f(w_L/w_p)\cdot P(w_L,w_P)/P(w_P)\  dw_L=0.6$$ for any weight $w_P>0,$ so:
\begin{array}{rlcl}
&\displaystyle \frac{1}{P(w_P)}\int_0^{w_p} \left[c_1-2/3 c\cdot \left(\frac{w_P}{w_L}\right)^{3/2}\right]\cdot P(w_L,w_P)\  dw_L &= 0.6 \\
\Rightarrow &\displaystyle c_1 -2/3 \cdot c \cdot w_P^{3/2}/P(w_P) \int_0^{w_P} w_L^{-3/2} \cdot P(w_L,w_P)\ dw_L & = 0.6
\end{array}